# Replace word in text BUT only if it is not contained in a specific pattern

Tags: javascript

I want to replace some word in a text BUT only if it is not contained in a specific pattern.
Specifically, in the text: **myWord class = 'someClass'>myWord</span> myWord**
the word I want to replace is **myWord** BUT only if it is not contained in the following pattern of the text: **class = 'someClass'>myWord</span>**. Could you please someone help me.

Input
***myWord** class = 'someClass'>**myWord**</span> **myWord***

Expected Output
***myWordReplaced** class = 'someClass'>**myWord**</span> **myWordReplaced***

```
<div id="myView"></div>

<script>
    vText = "myWord class = 'someClass'>myWord</span> myWord"; 
    vWord = "myWord";
    vRegExp = `(class = 'TransparentAndUnderline'>.*)${vWord}(.*<\/span>)`;
    const vNewRegExp = new RegExp(vRegExp, 'gi');

    vText = vText.replace(vWord, function() {
        if (!vNewRegExp.test(vText)) { // If it is not contained in the pattern, replace
            return 'myWordReplaced';
        } else {// Otherwise, do nothing
            return;
        }
    })

    document.getElementById("myView").innerHTML = vText;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate the pattern with one that matches `class='someClass'` and all of its contents, and use a replacer function. If the first alternation matches, replace with itself (so that there's no change); otherwise, replace with the replacement. For example:

```js
const pattern = /class *= *['"]someClass['"][^>]*>.*?<\/span>|myWord/g;

const str = `replace the following myWord but not the following <span class='someClass'>has myWord in it</span>`;

const result = str.replace(
  pattern,
  match => match === 'myWord' ? 'myWordReplaced' : match
);
console.log(result);
```

To construct the pattern dynamically, use

```
const vWord = 'myWord';
const pattern = new RegExp(String.raw`class *= *['"]someClass['"][^>]*>.*?<\/span>|${vWord}`, 'g');
```